# Javascript : How can I put this data in better way ? (string to array/object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, object

I have a string that could look like this :

```
str = "4bobsCat3carsOfThisGarage10this1that0whatever";
```

My string always starts with a number from 0 to 99, I have multiple character chains made up of lower and upper case letters separated by numbers from 0 to 99. This string is basically :

- number from 0 to 99
- characters a to z or A to Z

This pattern repeats itself a couple times.
I want to create an object/array to class this weird kind of data in a better way ...
It would be great if I could get something like :

```
array = [4, "bobsCat", 3, "carsOfThisGarage", 10, "this", 1, "that", 0, "whatever"]
```

Or like this :

```
object["bobsCat"] = {number : 4};
object["carsOfThisGarage"] = {number : 3};
object["this"] = {number : 10};
object["that"] = {number : 1};
object["whatever"] = {number : 0}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regex

```
let str = "4bobsCat3carsOfThisGarage10this1that0whatever";
let rx = /(\d{1,2})([a-zA-Z]+)/g;

var rxResult = null;
while (rxResult = rx.exec(str)) {
    // rxResult[1] will be your number
    // rxResult[2] will be text
    console.log(rxResult[1], rxResult[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the second object structure, you could use the new method [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), and unary plus operator to convert the digits to number type:

```js
let str = "4bobsCat3carsOfThisGarage10this1that0whatever";

let obj = {};
for (let [, dig, key] of str.matchAll(/(\d+)(\D+)/g)) {
    obj[key] = { number: +dig };
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
str.split(/(\d+)/)
```

You can also remove empty strings ("") by:

```
str.split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean)
```